# How to change weird PHP URL with htaccess code?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hoping someone can help me here. In my .htaccess file, I've got a rewrite rule written as:

```
RewriteRule ^/?wrestler/([^/]*)$ /wrestler.php?id=$1 [L]
```

for a URL that would be something like

```
localhost/wrestling.php?id=something
```

And now what I'm trying to do is change a URL like

```
localhost/category.php?id=something
```

to

```
localhost/id/category
```

The thing to note with this scenario is that this time I'm trying to use the **id** part as the thing after the first "/" and then add the category part after the second "/".

Below is what my entire .htacces file looks like at the moment.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?article/([^/]*)$ /article.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?wrestler/([^/]*)$ /wrestler.php?id=$1 [L]

# Removes the .php extension from pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Any thoughts guys?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/category/?$ /category.php?id=$1   [L]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)/([^\/]*)$ /$2.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

You need two captured parameters.

This expression was tested with http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/.

Comment: This is making all the images on my website go blank.

Comment: Well it's a very general expression so it surely matches other URLs that it should ignore. If you don't have more specifics on the category (let's say from a finite list for instance) or on the id part (let's say it is an integer for example) then you'll have to add some other rules above this one to protect your other resources. Do you have any more info on "id" and "category"?

Comment: Yes, I do. The id will ALWAYS be something like say 'hello' or 'hello-better-by' or even 'mega-bear'. It will always follow that kind of a pattern with those dashes. It will never be a number. The category will also follow the exact same pattern.

Comment: What pattern is this? just any string of letters? that doesn't help a lot... If i were you i'd prefix all those URLs with a path like "category" or "c" or "cat". That would become : `RewriteRule ^cat/([^\/]*)/([^\/]*)$ /$2.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA]` and it would match anything like `/cat/hello/mega-bear` whereas excluding the other URLs of your website (images ...).

Comment: Sorry, I missworded that. What I was trying to say was that if I had a URL like    /category.php?id=name&keyword=something how can I get that URL to be displayed as     /name/keyword ?

Comment: I think you're missing the point of URL rewriting. It will not "display" `/category.php?id=name&keyword=something` as `/name/keyword`, it is the other way round : it is the request of type (matching) `/name/keyword` that will be redirected (internally) to your `/category.php?id=name&keyword=something` script.

Comment: This is wrong answer. You need to have the second part `category` to be literally in the match section of the `RewriteRule`

Comment: @HerrSerker : please don't downvote without reading the question. the "category" part is required by OP to be rewritten.

Comment: @HerrSerker : So?? 1st captured param is `id` ($1), 2nd captured param is `category` ($2), as specified in `/id/category`, and is rewritten to `/$2.php?id=$1` as specified in `/category.php?id=something`, what is your problem? (and what is your solution?)

Comment: Right, but 2nd captured param should be just 'category' not any string. You should not capture 'category', just match. So it's like in Minhaz Ahmed's answer.

Comment: @HerrSerker : This is not true, read from OP : "and then add the **category part** after the second "/"", as you can see from their example htaccess that they're trying to rewrite the category part as "article" and then as "wrestler", and thus looking on SO for a more general solution, as the one i suggested.

Comment: `<id>/category` should become `category.php?id=<id>`, that's true. but `<a>/<b>` should not become `<b>.php?id=<a>`. The category part is static, not dynamic.

Comment: Come on are you trolling or what?? OP has already solved the case where only `id` is dynamic, this is how their question begins. THEN, they're asking for a more general rule where the `category` also becomes dynamic.

Comment: From my point of view he does not ask that. He asks about a different order.

Comment: @HerrSerker : "from my point of view" this does not justify a downvote. See here http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: This is a pointless discussion. You write from 'your point of view', too. But you did not type it.